# Caculating the homology of a Total complex

Tags: homology-cohomology, homological-algebra

I find it really hard when I try to finish the exercise 3.5.4 on weibel's ***Introduction to homological algebra***:

Let C be a second quadrant double complex with exact rows, and let $B_{pq}^{h}$ be the image of $d^{h}:C_{pq}\rightarrow C_{p-1,q}$.Show that $H_{p+q}Tot(T_{-p}C)\cong H_{q}(B^{h}_{p*},d^{v})$.
Here *Tot* refers to the total complex of the double complex $C_{*,*}$.

I tried many ways like using the former conclusion in **Application 3.5.11**:

$0\rightarrow colim^{1}H_{q+1}(Tot(T_{i}C))\rightarrow H_{q}(Tot(C)\rightarrow colim^{1}H_{q}(Tot(T_{i}C)\rightarrow 0$

is exact for each q. Here $colimt^{1}$ refers to the derived functor for colimit and $T_{i}C$ refers to the subcomplex cut off by the column $-i$. But this failed for sure. Some actual caculation was also done, but the homology group for $Tot(T_{i}C)$ is really complicated. So can you give me some hints?